# how to assign the value of a progressbar in another outerclass variable to perform calculation?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, class, android-activity

so i have been trying to make this BMI calculator in android studio, where your BMI will instantly get calculated  when you drag Progress-bar to any value .

To execute this, what i did was-

inside  the the Bundle class,

i directly declared 2 variable and assigned one of them to get the data from the Height progress bar and another to get the data from weight progress bar.

and then i wrote the typical code for the calculation and the text setting.

And it did not work

For myself being a very new to this, i really cant find my mistake here.

so as a result what i got was-  a still BMI which was the result for the initial value of the progress-bar that i have set for the height and weight.

i am getting a feeling that i made a very silly mistake somewhere that i still can not notice.
Would you be kind enough to point that out?

the Java code that i have used is below, please check it-

The code for the BMI is at the end. I feel the problem is lying there.

here is the screenshot of the app-

[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRWqN.jpg)

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RQhn.jpg)

here is my code--

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView mheighttext,mweighttext2,mbmitext,mfunnymsg;
    SeekBar mbar1, mbar2;
    RelativeLayout mweightlayout, mlayout3;
    ImageView mgincbtn1,mgincbtn2,mgdecbtn1,mgdecbtn2;

    String mbmi, bmitext;
    int wt= 45;
    String wtwt="45";
    int ht= 158;
    String htht="158";

    float rslt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        mheighttext=findViewById(R.id.heighttext);
        mweighttext2=findViewById(R.id.weighttext2);
        mbar1= findViewById(R.id.bar1);
        mbar2=findViewById(R.id.bar2);
        mgincbtn1=findViewById(R.id.gincbtn1);
        mgincbtn2=findViewById(R.id.gincbtn2);
        mgdecbtn1=findViewById(R.id.gdecbtn1);
        mgdecbtn2=findViewById(R.id.gdecbtn2);

        mbmitext=findViewById(R.id.bmitext1);
        mfunnymsg=findViewById(R.id.funnymsg);

        
        mbar1.setMax(246);
        mbar1.setProgress(160);

        mbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                ht=progress;
                htht=String.valueOf(ht);
                mheighttext.setText(htht);

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });


        mbar2.setMax(244);
        mbar2.setProgress(50);

        mbar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                
                wt=progress;
                wtwt=String.valueOf(wt);
                mweighttext2.setText(wtwt);
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });

        
        mgincbtn1.setOnClickListener(v -> {

            ht=ht+1;

            if (ht>=0 && ht<247) {

                mbar1.setProgress(ht);
                htht = String.valueOf(ht);
                mheighttext.setText(htht);

            }
        });

        
        mgdecbtn1.setOnClickListener(v -> {


            ht=ht-1;
            if (ht>=0 && ht<247) {

                mbar1.setProgress(ht);
                htht = String.valueOf(ht);
                mheighttext.setText(htht);

            }

        });
        
        mgincbtn2.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            wt=wt+1;

            if (wt>=0 && wt<244) {
                mbar2.setProgress(wt);
                wtwt = String.valueOf(wt);
                mweighttext2.setText(wtwt);
            }
        });
        
        mgdecbtn2.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            wt=wt-1;
            if (wt>=0 && wt<244) {

                mbar2.setProgress(wt);
                wtwt = String.valueOf(wt);
                mweighttext2.setText(wtwt);
            }
        });
        
        

            int htt = mbar1.getProgress();
            int wtt = mbar2.getProgress();
            float httt=htt/100;
            rslt= wtt/(httt*httt);
            mbmi=Float.toString(rslt);
            mbmitext.setText(mbmi);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your variable naming conventions are not very clear to know which button is which but I guess it is because the calculation is done irrespective of the state in of your application. Try adding a button that computes and then move the computation code to a method that will be invoked when the button is clicked

Answer (score 1):

You would want to put the snippet of code that calculates the BMI (perhaps the last 4 lines of code) in both `onProgressChanged()` to instantly calculate BMI as height/weight gets changed. Since you're setting global variables for both height and weight, you'll get current values for each of them.

You can also make a function for calculating the BMI like this:

```
private float calculateBMI(int height, int weight) {
    float ht = height / 100;
    float result = weight / (ht * ht);
    return result;
}
```

and have this function call in both `onProgressChanged()` like so (for the **weight** for example):

```
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        wt = progress;
        mweighttext2.setText(String.valueOf(getBMI(ht, progress)));    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this your code...

```
int htt = mbar1.getProgress();
        int wtt = mbar2.getProgress();
        float httt=htt/100;
        rslt= wtt/(httt*httt);
        mbmi=Float.toString(rslt);
        mbmitext.setText(mbmi);
```

to a method say

```
    public void computeBMI(){
      int htt = mbar1.getProgress();
      int wtt = mbar2.getProgress();
      float httt=htt/100;
      rslt= wtt/(httt*httt);
      mbmi=Float.toString(rslt);
      mbmitext.setText(mbmi);
    }
```

Then add a button in your UI say mCompute. In your oncreate method you can then implement that buttons onClickListener to call computeBMI() above.

That is:

```
yourButton.setOnclickListener((v)->{
   computeBMI();
});
```

Comment: This would not instantly calculate and display BMI as the user changes height/weight.